# apply regsub for certain line in a paragraph in tcl

Tags: tcl

This is the group of lines in which I have assigned to test variable

```
    set test {tkt(pnr(
                    ticket(20140414,130559),
                    fbcode(y),
                    etkt(yes),
                    entry(price),
                    trap([flist,186,tkt1,bag],[start(1)]),
                    city(y)
            ])).}
```

I need to search some list of values from "**trapremlist**" variable inside "trap([flist,186,tkt1,bag]".

```
    set trapremlist {bag bagdisclosure bt}
```

If any value from **trapremlist** is there in the "trap([flist,186,tkt1,bag]". then I need to remove the same. In this case I need to remove "bag".

I thought to extract the list inside the trap([] and using the lsearch remove the value if it is there in trapremlist.

But I couldn't get the list inside the trap([]  and update the list back after parshing

Could you advise the best way to handle this ?

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “cheap hack” method is to use `string map`:

```
set mapping {}
foreach value $trapremlist {
    # Sneaky point: remove version with leading comma first
    lappend mapping ",$value" "" $value ""
}
set removed [string map $mapping $test]
```

This is going to blow up nastily if you've got any of the words in the removal list anywhere else. If that's the case, you've got to parse and reconstruct. Fortunately, we can probably do that line-wise in this case:

```
set result {}
foreach line [split $test "\n"] {
    if {[regexp {^(\s*trap\(\s*\[)([\w,]+)(\].*\)\s*),\s*$} $line -> a b c]} {
        set b2 {}
        foreach bit [split $b ","] {
            if {$bit ni $trapremlist} {
                lappend b2 $bit
            }
        }
        set line $a[join $b2 ","]$c
    }
    lappend result $line
}
set removed [join $result "\n"]
```

You can go to fuller parsing if you get an actual parser working (there's a parser generator engine in tcllib) but it's a lot of work if something as simple as the above is good enough.

Comment: The second solution is awesome for my requirement. Thank you.